# Как получить значение STATIC_URL в view.py?

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Добрый день! Вопрос наверное смешной. Но для меня это целая проблема. Хочу из view приложения django обращаться к статическим файлам приложения

Сначала думал, решение простое: `from settings import STATIC_URL`
Но view.py находится во вложенной папке по отношению к settings.py, поэтому интерпретатор выдает ошибку

Читал про findstatic. Но она получает абсолютный путь, кроме того ищет необходимое сочетание во всей статик-папке, что мне не нужно. Мне всего лишь нужно получить обычную строковую константу '/static/'

Comment: А зачем? Какую задачу вы решаете? В django очень развитые средства работы со статикой, использовать `STATIC_URL` напрямую почти никогда не нужно

Comment: `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.STATIC_URL)`

Comment: [godva](@godva), спасибо. Вроде оно. andreymal, вот я и не понял, какие

Comment: [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal), Например мне нужно прочитать файл из папки '/static/', заранее зная его имя